# Set child fragment's ViewPager page from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I have a fragment with a `ViewPager` (`fragment_main`) inside my `MainActivity`.
On my `MainActivity` I have a `BottomNavigationView`. I want to set the `fragment_main`'s `ViewPager`' page when I click the items of `BottomNavigationView`.
how can I do that?

PS: I already made it work but I don't think I used a good way.I got a refrence to my `ViewPager` inside my fragment and I set the Item:

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            MainFragment mainFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_item_feed:
                    mainFragment =(MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frame);
                    mainFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

It works!
But the problem is: what if I have another fragment on my `MainActivity`?
Sure, I can replace it with fragment_main first but it takes time and
`mainFragment =(MainFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frame)` returns null.

So whats the best way to set fragment's viewpager's page, Inside parent activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use **FrameLayout**   instead of ViewPager for Fragments

Use below line in your case statement inside bottomNavigationView click listener.

```
toFrag(ProductsFrag.newInstance(FragInstance.PRODUCTS));

    public void toFrag(Fragment toFrag){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, toFrag).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                        }
                    }, 200);
}
```

here R.id.conent is **FrameLayout** id